# Should custom Django Admin be separate from client endpoints?

Tags: rest, api-design, django, client-server

I am currently in the process of creating a Django REST framework project for a client server web app. I would like to ask the following:

1. Should I write a custom admin if I want my app to be production ready, or is the DRF admin sufficient?
2. If I were to write a custom admin page, should I separate admin endpoints from client endpoints? This confuses me. I have a model called Portfolio. Clients can view, update and delete only those portfolios that they own, as well as add new ones. Admins on the other hand, can view all portfolios. If I wanted to implement a custom admin solution, should I create one endpoint that can do all those actions and limit it with strict user permissions, or should I just create an endpoint for admins and an endpoint for clients? Creating two endpoints looks like violation of DRY principle?

All help and advice is appreciated!